# PayPal Sandbox Business Account - Confirm Email for API Access

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created an HK business sandbox account and it said we need to confirm the email in order to use PayPal API. But I cannot find the confirmation email in Sandbox Test Accounts > Notifications. I waited for a few days but still no email received. Is there anyone know how to confirm the email?

Answer (score 0):

Add the guide [here](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/934/session/L3RpbWUvMTM3ODI4Mjk1NS9zaWQvZnhSUEtzemw%3D) for your reference on creating sandbox account. The email for this new created account will be confirmed by default. You don't need to do it in sandbox as the email is fake.

Comment: when I click "Profile" of a sandbox account, it shows "Your request is still processing, please wait..." and I have waited for a few days already.